# Footer obstructing other elements

Tags: html, css

I am building a lightweight chat-like web page. However, the footer is getting in front of the other elements. The CSS code:

```
#page_content {
   margin-left: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#footer {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.980392);
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   position: relative;
}
```

An example are here: http://jsfiddle.net/6BrjV/ THanks for your help.

Comment: side note, I would recommend using some layout framework, twitter bootstrap for example might help... will save you tons of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your floats:

```
#footer {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.980392);
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6BrjV/1/)**

Comment: However, in order for it to work correctly, I needed to add height: 100% to the body style.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the page:

```
#page {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;      /* I would recommend this after floating elements */
}
```

Comment: ok, it works (overflow: hidden), but I'm really not sure I understand why? care to explain? I'm scratching my head

Comment: It essentially makes room after floating elements. Check this out: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/

Comment: gee, 12 years of HTML and CSS experience, you learn new things every day... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can tack it to the bottom. Use this CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#page_content {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#footer {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.980392);
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rj8tt/

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `#page_content` is collapsing upon itself, as the child elements are being floated, and thus removed from the flow of the document.

Add `overflow:hidden` to `#page_content`, thus forcing the parent to contain the children elements.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kS7pN/)

```
#page_content {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using some inline styles to float some elements. I put in a simple micro-clearfix hack to see what it did and it looks like it should solve your problems. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/6BrjV/5/

```
div:before, div:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
div:after {
    clear: both;
}
```